# How do I update values for individual rows quickly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns of data in an excel sheet. One is `id_upload` and the other is `id_work`. How do I update the works table so that the correct `id_work` has the right value updated into the column `id_upload`?

There are 23 columns in the works table so I need to be specific in updating only the `id_upload` column, and it needs to get the correct row (via `id_work`).

Here's a sample of the update data:

```
id_upload  id_work
15           331
16           370
17           689
18           690
19           765
```

Currently the works table does not have any values in the `id_upload` field. There's 80 rows of updates to go through and I'd rather not do it manually :).

Comment: this might help you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Hmm some of the rows have values in them, my current query cuts those ones out...can I do it jointly like... this?


`SELECT * FROM smf_works_works WHERE id_type IN(11,13,14,16,18) AND id_upload = "" ORDER BY id_work ASC
INSERT INTO smf_works_works (id_upload) VALUES(15,62) ON DUPLICATE KEY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a single query.  That's just asking for trouble.  It's not hard to use Excel to create several queries.

Since you neglected to supply the actual schema for your table, I'm assuming the name is `smf_works_works`, that `id_work` is the primary and only key, and that id_upload in Excel should be assigned to the `id_upload` field of `smf_works_works`.  I'm also assuming all fields are integer or numeric fields.

Let column A in Excel be id_upload.  Let column B in Excel be id_work.  Let row 1 be column headers and row 2 and below be data.

In the column C in Excel, enter this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO smf_works_works (id_work, id_upload) VALUES (",B2,",",A2,") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_upload = ",A2,";")
```

Now fill down column C for your 80 rows.  Now select the column, and paste it into a text editor and verify that it looks right.  Then paste it into MySQL Workbench or your preferred query analyzer, and run the first row.  Use a `SELECT` statement to verify that the data are correct.  Now run the remaining 79 rows.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That's really awesome!!! I think I will have to use this technique again for sure, thanks so so much!!

Comment: Hmm it's not working quite right it's giving me an error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET id_upload = 15' at line 1" The query we made is:
 
`INSERT INTO smf_works_works (id_work, id_upload) VALUES (331,15) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET id_upload = 15;`

Comment: @JadeElizabeth Oh, I messed up the syntax.  There's no `SET` keyword.  It should be `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_upload = ...`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Works perfectly now, you've saved me so much time now and into the future, thank you so so so so so so much!!! :D